# Calling a Flask-Wtform submit button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, flask, flask-wtforms

I've been trying to set up a multistep form on my Flask app.

I found this tutorial on w3schools which was very helpful: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_form_steps.asp

With a few tweaks to the code, the form rendered properly as shown in the tutorial.

My code looks something like this:

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" name="register_workplace_form", name="form" class="regForm" id="regForm" action="/">

{{ form.hidden_tag() }}

<div class="form-group"> 
   <h3 class="form_labels">{{ _('Register Workplace') }} </h3> 
</div>                

<div class="form-group tab">
     {{render_field_with_errors(form.name, class='form-control',placeholder='Name of Workplace') }}
</div>
.
.
.Several other 'form-group tab' divs
.
.
<div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">

      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)" class="btn btn-primary">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>


      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 " id="final">
          {{ form.submit(class='btn btn-primary pull-left final') }}
        </div>
      </div>

     </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var currentTab = 0;
showTab(currentTab);

function showTab(n) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }

  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("final").style.display = "inline";
       <!--document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";-->
  } else {
    document.getElementById("final").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }

  // ... and run a function that displays the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;

  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";

  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;

  // if you have reached the end of the form... :
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {

  //...the form gets submitted:

    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid;
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {

  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  //... and adds the "active" class to the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
```

And my views.py

```
@public.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def index():
    form = workplaceForm()

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        workplace = Workplace( \
                      name=form.name.data,created_at=datetime.now(),status='active')
        db.session.add(workplace)
        db.session.commit
        flash('You have successfully registered your workplace, pending registration fee payment.')

    return render_template('index.html', form = form)
```

However for some reason the submit button on the final tab is a dud, it does not execute any action when clicked.

I've tried changing it to a simple button inside input tags as well as reverting it to the original w3school's code with similar results.

What should I do differently to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To whoever might find themselves with a similar problem I fixed it so:

Instead of keeping the submit button on its own, I fixed it into the last 'form-group-tab' div

```
<div class="form-group tab">
 {{render_field_with_errors(form.premAddr, class='form-control', placeholder='Address of Premise') }}
 {{ form.submit(class='btn btn-primary pull-left final') }}
</div>
```

I then edited the javascript logic to stop displaying the 'next' button in the final tab:

```
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").style.display = "none";

  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
```

Hope it helps